# Replicating the BBC website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the BBC Website. And I'm almost through the first part of navigation bar styling on the top.

[image]

I'm having issues in the last part on the more section and with that triangle arrow. As soon as i insert that arrow, it breaks my design, any help appreciated.

If you notice in the image above, the text "More" and that triangle arrow are slightly placed lower than the other elements. But, if I remove that triangle arrow from my code, "More" aligns perfectly with the others. So, I'm unable to get a fix for that issue of having the more and the arrow on the same alignment as other tags in the nav bar.

Also i would like to know if we can style a `placeholder` value?
Here is the code for reference.

```css
body,
p,
div,
ul,
li,
span,
input {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFD;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
  background-color: #E7E8E1;
}
#topnav {
  background-color: black
  /*#7a0000*/
  ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 41px;
}
.page-width {
  width: 1268px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#topnav-logo {
  padding: 5.5px 14px 2px 0px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
#topnav-signin {
  font-stretch: semi-expanded;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1px 87px 13px 13px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666
  /*black*/
  ;
  float: left;
}
#topnav-signin img {
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
#topnav-menu {
  float: left;
}
#topnav-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 13px 20px 12px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
  float: left;
}
#topnav-menu ul li span {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 57px
}
#topnav-search {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 2px 18px;
}
#topnav-search input {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 143px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle
}
#topnav-search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My BBC</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="topnav">
      <div class="page-width">
        <div id="topnav-logo">
          <img src="images/bbclogo.PNG" />
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-signin">
          <p>
            <img src="images/signinlogo.PNG" />Sign in</p>
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Sport</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Earth</li>
            <li>Travel</li>
            <li>Capital</li>
            <li>Culture</li>
            <li>More<span>&#9654</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
          <img src="images/search.PNG" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? I remember a similar question before.

Comment: Why not just save an offline copy of the BBC site as appears on your device and work from that source code? Also try getting in touch with the BBC directly and seeing if they will help you. On a slightly more serious note, can you tell us what you've tried, what your outcome shold be, why it's not worked and then remove the code that doesn't apply to those questions. Thanks

Comment: "It breaks" is not a good description. Please specify the issue in DETAIL possibly with a screen shot of the broken css. I copy pasted your code and it looks fine on certain widths, however it has responsiveness issues

Comment: certainly some issues with responsiveness, but the only break I can see related to the arrow is the fact its vertically misaligned with the text next to it stretching the container by a few pixels.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, for such bad description. Apologies for that.The thing is, if you can notice in the image above, the text "More and that triangle arrow" are slightly placed lower than the other elements. But, if I remove that triangle arrow from my code, "more" aligns perfectly with other. So, I'm unable to get a fix for that issue, having the more and the arrow on the same alignment as other tags in the nav bar.

Comment: @Aziz no, not a school assignment. It's for an online course on web development.

Comment: @sinanspd sorry, for bad description. Image i've provide is of broken css only. The broken part is more section with that triangluar arrow. After adding that arrow, the more section shifts a lil' bit below than the other tags in the nav bar. But, if i remove the triangular arrow, it fits in perfectly fine.

Comment: @nepeo yes, i agree. the responsiveness is a total mess. I have begun on html and css a few days back. so, surely will take some time to get my hands on. I've replied my problem back in other replies. If you could help with that, would be great. Thanks

Comment: That's okay, we all have to start somewhere! Once you think you've got the basics down look up CSS media queries and responsive design, one of the most important skills for CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with the arrow is related to the joys of inline vertical alignment, if you look at where the spans block has been positioned in chrome's element inspector (developer tools) it is a few pixels lower than the text next to it.

Normally issues like this are to do with the height of the block and where it's aligning with the neighbouring block. In this case the easy way to fix it is to set the parent to a fixed height, now everything will be nice and level.

If you haven't seen chrome's element inspector I highly recommend checking it out, it gives you an easy way to see how things are working and modify them on the fly. Both safari and firefox have similar tools as well. Most of what I learnt came from using this to figure out how certain websites work with trial and error.

```css
body,
p,
div,
ul,
li,
span,
input {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFD;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
  background-color: #E7E8E1;
}
#topnav {
  background-color: black
  /*#7a0000*/
  ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 41px;
}
.page-width {
  width: 1268px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#topnav-logo {
  padding: 5.5px 14px 2px 0px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
#topnav-signin {
  font-stretch: semi-expanded;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1px 87px 13px 13px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666
  /*black*/
  ;
  float: left;
}
#topnav-signin img {
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
#topnav-menu {
  float: left;
}
#topnav-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 13px 20px 12px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
  float: left;
}
#topnav-menu ul li span {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 57px;
  
}
#topnav-search {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 2px 18px;
}
#topnav-search input {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 143px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle
}
#topnav-search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My BBC</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="topnav">
      <div class="page-width">
        <div id="topnav-logo">
          <img src="images/bbclogo.PNG" />
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-signin">
          <p>
            <img src="images/signinlogo.PNG" />Sign in</p>
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Sport</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Earth</li>
            <li>Travel</li>
            <li>Capital</li>
            <li>Culture</li>
            <li>More<span>&#9654</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="topnav-search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
          <img src="images/search.PNG" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```